# Populate DataGrid from ComboBox selection (Linq to SQL)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, mvvm

Developing a WPF app here. I have a Linq to SQL class holding several tables in the designer.

I have a combo box which is populated on InitializeComponent with the 'Table_Name' column of a meta data table from SQL server...

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DBConnDataContext db = new DBConnDataContext();

        var query = from s in db.tbdbDownloadTables
                    where s.Include == "Y" && s.Table_Schema == "ref" && s.WhereClause == null && s.CCCP == null
                    select s.Table_Name;

        ComboBox.ItemsSource = query;          

    }
```

This all works fine :)

I have an adjacent data grid which I would like to populate on the user's ComboBox selection. How do I reference the ComboBox selection (Table_Name) column to the table I want to populate my DataGrid? I'm trying to use Mapping.GetTables to create a list of tables in the context but not sure where to go from here...

```
public void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        string ComboBoxValue = ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        DBConnDataContext db2 = new DBConnDataContext();

        //var tableModel = (from tables in db2.Mapping.GetTables() select tables.TableName).ToList(); ????


        var query2 = from tab in db2.tbdbDownloadTables
                     where tab.Table_Name == ComboBoxValue
                     select tab;

         TableGrid.ItemsSource = query2;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your ComboBox.SelectedItem is going to be an object of tbdbDownloadTable so you might try casting the sender to that.

```
var myTable = sender as tbdbDownloadTables;
```

Then you can use the properties in the table.